# Calculate a KPI based on multiple variables

Tags: finance

I am trying to create a KPI based on the disbursement of loans by the sales team. I want to base this KPI on a formula that takes into account the size of the loan, the tenor or term of the loan and the APR of the loan.

Additionally, I would like to tailor this KPI to different regions - tying it to purchasing power parity of a country for example.

So I have a separate KPI for someone selling in the UK vs someone selling in Turkey.

Comment: Do you have a measure that you can use to baseline the outcome?  For example loan in good standing, or default?

Comment: Hi Ralph! The loan is in good standing. With loan tenors varying between 30, 60 and 90 days. The APR on a monthly basis would equate to roughly 2%.  Loan amounts are expected to be from $5000 to $10 Million.

Comment: Here is a good link for developing KPI's.  Sorry I don't know enough about your objective or what data you have.   Once the objective is thought out, points 4,5,6 in the link are reasonable actions that you would need to take.  https://kpi.org/KPI-Basics/KPI-Development